# The stateSave in jQuery DataTables is not working when loading data table for the first time

Tags: jquery, datatables

The `stateSave` in jQuery DataTables is not working when loading data table for the first time, it loads filter data of previous state. It works fine after first load.

For example- If I have performed filter search and logout & login again in the application or update the cache and load this data table again then filter value of previous search will be visible and if there was nothing in previous search then value of filter will be blank. And next search onwards the filter works fine.

```
jQuery('#tableName').dataTable( {
    "Destroy": true,
    "Paginate": true,
    "StateSave": true,
    "StateDuration": 0.1
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`stateDuration` defines the mode of storage as well as the duration in seconds after which the saved state will be invalidated. This should be an integer (see https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateDuration), so the behaviour with provided value 0.1 is undefined.

All the options are named in camelCase. `Paginate` does not exist, you probably mean `paging`.

```
jQuery('#tableName').dataTable( {
    destroy: true,
    paging: true,
    stateSave: true,
    stateDuration: -1
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5y6fc8Lx/)

For an overview of all the options see https://datatables.net/reference/option/.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! Even if there is any issue with the code, it should never work. But, it is working always except the first time. Anyhow, I have modified the code as suggested, but issue remains the same.

Comment: @DevanshuKetle You are right, the configuration I provided was still not correct. The remaining problem was with stateDuration (see linked documentation in updated post). I also provided a Fiddle with a working example (just reload the page after e.g. searching).